# Elastic Beanstalk Docker container running Node application exits early

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ElasticBeanstalk environment with docker that deploys a node application running restify. When we deploy new versions of the application we see intermittent failures with the error:

`Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: nginx: [emerg] no host in upstream ":8080"`

When looking through the logs we see that the container exits with `exit 0` meaning the application is returning that it has exited successfully.

### Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY .npmrc .npmrc   
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/ 
RUN npm install 
RUN rm -f .npmrc

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080 CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: CMD should launch the long running process.

CMD `npm start` would launch the application through a gulp task that spawned a process to start the node application server.

Once the application process was spawned the gulp task would complete. Once gulp completed, the process would report to docker that it completed successfully and so the container would exit. To fix this I changed the docker file CMD to :

`CMD ["npm", "run", "start-node"]`

start-node runs the commands `node dist/app.js`

So now the process launched by CMD is the application server instead of the process that spawned a child-process that would start the application.